# How to Simulate or Trigger Enter or Return key programmatically in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, keypress

I have a camera scanner app that scans barcodes and the result is returned to an `Entry` field.

I can focus that `Entry` field but I can't get it to press enter programmatically, is there a way to do this in Xamarin.Forms?

My Target platform is Android.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: *"but I can't get it to press enter programmatically,"*  Please show code that you have tried, that did not work. Show enough of the surrounding code, that others can give an answer appropriate to your situation. Perhaps you were close, and a slight change to what you tried will fix it.

Comment: Also, *What do you want to happen?*  You say "Press enter programmatically", but I don't know what you want to happen, when the code does the equivalent of `Enter`. It is likely that a better solution is for the code to DIRECTLY do ... whatever `Enter` would do.

Comment: Thanks a lot ToolmakerSteve, I wanted to simulate or trigger Enter while I am on a specific `Entry` field as stated on the headline, I already solved the problem, I will paste the answer as a solution, thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a small replication of the problem, which is fairly simple.

in XAML:

```
<Entry Name="entry" Completed="OnCompleted"/>
<Label Name="label"/>
<Button Text="PRESS ENTER" Clicked="OnButtonPressed"/>
```

in C# or code behind I have:

```
void OnCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    label.Text = entry.Text;
}

void OnButtonPressed (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // we will be adding this code here at the last step
}
```

then create an `Interface` because the only easy way to do this is by using the native android functionality through a `DependencyService`:

```
public Interface IEnterService
{
    void PressEnter();
}
```

Then in the Android Project you need to create a class for example: `EnterService`
and implement the previous created interface like this:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(EnterService))]
namespace TestEnterPressed.Droid
{
    [Register("sendKeyDownUpSync", "(I)V", "GetSendKeyDownUpSync_IHandler")]
    class EnterService : IEnterService
    {
        public void PressEnter()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ENTER IS PRESSED");
            Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
                
                /* run your code here */
                inst.SendKeyDownUpSync(Keycode.Enter);
            }).Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the last step use your `DependencyService` to simulate Enter pressed through a button other than the keyboard or after scanning a barcode with a camera you can do it like this:

```
void OnButtonPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    entry.Focus();
    DependencyService.Get<IEnterService>().PressEnter();
}
```

I hope this is useful to somebody, thanks a bunch everyone :)

Comment: Hi Shibit.. I have a similar problem with Maui for Android: I use an external Bluetooth barcode reader but when I read a code, I need to simulate tapping the enter button on the Android keypad.
Do you have any ideas or suggestions?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The Enter or Return key press would triger the `Completed` event. I use a button to set the focus to the entry and then simulate the Entry press in Focused event.

```
    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        entry.Focus();
    }

    private void entry_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        entry_Completed(sender, e);
    }

    private void entry_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        entry.Text = "Hello";
        entry.Unfocus();
    }
```

Comment: hi Wendy, thanks a bunch, I tried this but it only focuses the `Entry` field and pops the soft keyboard, my button doesn't replace the (Enter or Return) character which is what I intend to do, thank you so much for your effort. :)